# Does this type of matrix have a name?

Tags: matrices

I am using a square matrix that has the same values on the diagonal (say, alpha) and a different value for all diagonal elements (say, beta).  Does this type of matrix have a name?  It is such a special form of a Toeplitz matrix that it surely must have its own name!

Comment: Are you describing a [Circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)?

Comment: There is quite an extensive list of matrices [here](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/special.html)

Comment: It is also a special case of a circulant matrix.  The a 4d version of the matrix is {a, b, b, b//b, a, b, b//b, b, a, b//b, b, b, a}.  Thank you for the list... I will look through it thoroughly!